# Is Rust's memmap safe to use if you're just treating the data as bytes?

Tags: rust, mmap, unsafe

Rust's [`memmap` crate](https://crates.io/crates/memmap) has `unsafe` methods.

I can understand how the returned address space is unsafe to pass to constructors which might validate its contents and then continue to use it.

I'm writing a binary-diff tool which only treats the returned address space as containing bytes (of any value) and does no validation on the contents of the address space.

Can I avoid propagating the `unsafe` in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the main principles of using `unsafe` correctly is that you take responsibility for ensuring soundness in all affected code - including the *safe* code that surrounds it.

If you were to expose this function in a library crate, you should mark it as `unsafe`; users of your library need to understand where UB arises and make their own decisions about safety.

In an application crate, you are in control of all of the code and it's up to you to never dereference the bytes as anything else. If you do that, it is completely acceptable to limit the `unsafe` code to where you directly interact with the memory map, wrapped in safe functions. In fact, wrapping *everything* in `unsafe` is counterproductive because it will be unclear where the danger lies.

Comment: Thanks, I've decided to create two APIs - with an unsafe constructor for the one which uses `memmap` and a safe constructor for "traditional" I/O.  On Linux I cannot prevent an external root process from truncating the mapped file, leading to a crash (but not UB) so I must mark the `memmap`'ed code as unsafe in some way, as a warning.

Answer (score 4):

It's a shame that memmap does not document its safety contract.  Indeed there is [an open issue from 2017](https://github.com/danburkert/memmap-rs/issues/32#issuecomment-299681476) on this very point.

I followed [this discussion in the RustSec/advisory-db repo re the crate's apparent abandonment](https://github.com/RustSec/advisory-db/issues/359#issuecomment-714224097) to [this safety documentation in the forked mapr crate](https://docs.rs/mapr/0.8.0/mapr/struct.Mmap.html#safety), which states:

> All file-backed memory map constructors are marked `unsafe` because of the potential for *Undefined Behavior* (UB) using the map if the underlying file is subsequently modified, in or out of process. Applications must consider the risk and take appropriate precautions when using file-backed maps. Solutions such as file permissions, locks or process-private (e.g. unlinked) files exist but are platform specific and limited.

This safety concern should obviously be relevant in memmap too.

Comment: OP seems to be familiar with the specific safety concern. To me, the question is about whether to propagate the unsafe attributes throughout the codebase vs keeping them local to the interaction with mmap.

Comment: I had understood the question differently: is it possible to encapsulate the unsafe behaviour such that it need not be propagated to consumers?  In which case, the answer is “yes, provided you prevent the underlying file from being modified without the consumer’s knowledge”.